# Linux GRE keep alive

Tags: cisco, routing, ipsec, keepalive, gre

What are possibilities in Linux kernel (?) to work with Cisco endpoint encorporating GRE keep-alives? We have GRE IPsec tunnel set up with another company. We would like to have backup tunnel which should be active when main one dies. So they enable GRE keep-alives on the first one which will detect failure and switch routing to the backup tunnel. We are dependent on technology proposed by them (another solutions can't be used). How can we accomplish such communication? I was surprised finding nothing about it in iproute2 nor kernel. Only [this](https://github.com/PaulTimmins/linux-gre-keepalive) popped up, but it does not seem to be reliable for production use.

UPDATE:

Our current configuration is:

- **Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS**, kernel **3.13.0-24-generic**
- **racoon** and **setkey** daemon for managing IPsec
- **iproute2** for bringing tunnel up in **gre mode**

We **must** use GRE keep-alives. They told us there is no way (well, not technically, but I guess it's their policy) to establish backup tunnel unless we enable keep-alives.

The question is, is it possible using server configuration mentioned above?

Comment: This could lead to much subjective discussion; you might improve the post by adding configurations/setups that you have tried, and any issues that might have arisen from them.  Or perhaps by clarifying the question, i.e. asking just "is this possible".  Also adding details about the Cisco endpoint (versions, make/model, etc) could help folks to provide more relevant solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This is related only partially to keepalives. Basically you need to establish a second GRE tunnel and implement some mechanism to detect tunnel failures (though it can be done with keepalives, usually it's done with *HELO* protocol messages or *BFD* protocol layer on top of dynamic routing, designed especially for this purpose). A common approach will be using any sort of dynamic routing, but not *RIP* (regardless of it's version) - since *RIP* isn't suited for multi-path operations and basically holds only one route for a destination. *OSPF* will be fine, *EIGRP* (but since it's proprietary, you cannot use it on Linux since there's no open implementations of it), *IS-IS*, *iBGP*.

You can also consider getting rid of GRE and implement a *VTI* tunnel, since Linux kernel is capable of it.